# easyphp 17.0 can not connect to the internet

Tags: wordpress, connect, easyphp

I have one question in new version of easyphp, Wordpress and Plugins can not update automatically.
Of course, my system is connected to the Internet, but updates not work.
please help me.
thank you.

Comment: Are you sure you had enabled the cURL module?

Comment: yes, but dont work!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question.
This problem is related to the C-Url.
You must enable the C-Url to solve the problem.
tnx.